# Error not all code paths return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have the following function but I am getting the following error: not all code path returns value.

```
public Int64 id(string fd, string tb)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    else
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX (" + fd + ") FROM " + tb + "", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
        Int64 I = Convert.ToInt64((cmd.ExecuteScalar().Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : cmd.ExecuteScalar())) + 10;
        return I;
    }                
}
```

Please help me understand why this is happening and how to correct it.

Comment: Please consider removing unrelated code demonstrating SQL injection from your post. Also consider reading MSDN documentation about error (available by clicking F1 when error is selected in VS or by searching by error code shown in build output). If it does not help - please edit your post to format code with consistent indentation.

Comment: Yup. You do have that error in your code. What was your question?

Comment: actually i found only a place to write code but where should i write quetion , i m new guide me

Comment: return I must be outside the brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Int64 id(string fd, string tb)
{
    Int64 I = 0;

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    else
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX (" + fd + ") FROM " + tb + "", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
        I = Convert.ToInt64((cmd.ExecuteScalar().Equals(DBNull.Value) ? 0 : cmd.ExecuteScalar())) + 10;
    }
    return I; 
}
```

The *return I* statement was inside the *if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)* block. This means it wouldn't have been called it the con.State wasn't closed and the function wouldn't have returned anything. I is initialised to 0 at the top of the function, so this will be returned if the SQL query isn't run.

Comment: I fixed a bug where 'I' wasn't initialized, improved formatting and also added some explanation. This code still has significant problems however. It will only run the SQL command if the connection was initially open. It opens and closes connections for reasons I can't fathom, It is vulnerable to SQL injection and the variable names could be better...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is very simple. You return a value only if the condition: "con.State == ConnectionState.Closed" is true. Otherwise there is no return value, that is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: thanx actually after tht i tried try catch and return true in catch and it works in vs 2012 pro but error was not in vs 2010, thanx again